# Switches in ios

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I am a mere beginner in iOS. I have seen this statement ** `[leftSwitch setOn:setting animated:YES];`** in a tutorial describing about switches.

```
    UISwitch *leftSwitch;


    UISwitch *whichSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    BOOL setting = whichSwitch.isOn;
   [leftSwitch setOn:setting animated:YES];
```

Please explain me the need of keyword `animated` in this context.Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried both YES and NO and observed the results?

Comment: @  ElJay i have observed the results.I would like to know its real programmatic working

Comment: I recommend a book about the language. :) objC is/looks to be a BIT different at times. Programming in cocoa by hildegrass is a classic. (Anyway, see my answer for this question) the info about the book is friendly advice

Comment: The class reference from Apple (there is a link to the specific class for UISwitch, is a great resource IMO.

Comment: @ElJay he does not ask bout the button abut about the language itself

Comment: @Daij-Djan UIButton IS part of the language, as is the class reference that describes the button.

Comment: @Elay no its part of CLASS LIBRARY called UIKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in objC, parameters dont come behind the method name like in C or java or ...
in objC, parameters are interwoven with the method name..

```
lalalaa:PARAM lalala:PARAM2 lalala:PARAM3
```

after every : comes a ONE param

so animated: = part of method name

```
setOn:animated:
```

Answer (score 0):

The `animated` part of that method determines where the changing of that switch state is a nice smooth animation or not.  Try both `YES` and `NO` and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

setOn:animated:
Set the state of the switch to On or Off, optionally animating the transition.

- (void)setOn:(BOOL)on animated:(BOOL)animated
  Parameters
  on
  YES if the switch should be turned to the On position; NO if it should be turned to the Off position. If the switch is already in the designated position, nothing happens.

animated
YES to animate the “flipping” of the switch; otherwise NO.
SEE: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: look for Dash in the app store. This app has docs for a lot of langs/frameworks. Will help a lot in the dev process.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop `UISwitch` in `xib` file.

In `.h` file:

```
IBOutlet UISwitch *onoff;
```

In `.m` file:

```
[onoff addTarget:self action:@selector(switchTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// Switch
-(void) switchTapped: (id) sender {
    UISwitch *switchControl = (UISwitch*) sender;
    BOOL value = switchControl.isOn;
    if (value) {
        lbl4.text=@"ON";
    }else{
        lbl4.text=@"OFF";
    }
}
```